# Beam: CombinePerKey(max) hang in dataflow job

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am try to load data from `GCS` through `pub\sub` way, and fetch user max level by `userid`. The following codes runs well in `DirectRunner` but job is hang in `CombinePerKey(max)` in dataflow.

Here are the codes

```py
class ParseAndFilterFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        text_line = element.strip()
        data = {}
        try:
            data = json.loads(text_line.decode('utf-8'))
            if 'user_id' in data and data['user_id'] and 'level' in data and data['level']:
                yield {
                    'user': data['user_id'],
                    'level': data['level'],
                    'ts': data['ts']
                }

def str2timestamp(t, fmt="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"):
    return time.mktime(datetime.strptime(t, fmt).timetuple())

class FormatFieldValueFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        yield {
            "field": element[0],
            "value": element[1]
        }

...

        raw_event = (
                    p
                    | "Read Sub Message" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=args.topic)
                    | "Convert Message to JSON" >> beam.Map(lambda message: json.loads(message))
                    | "Extract File Name" >> beam.ParDo(ExtractFileNameFn())
                    | "Read File from GCS" >> beam.io.ReadAllFromText()
            )

        filtered_events = (
            raw_event
            | "ParseAndFilterFn" >> beam.ParDo(ParseAndFilterFn())
        )

        raw_events = (
            filtered_events
            | "AddEventTimestamps" >> beam.Map(lambda elem: beam.window.TimestampedValue(elem, str2timestamp(elem['ts'])))
        )

        window_events = (
            raw_events
            | "UseFixedWindow" >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(5 * 60))
        )

        user_max_level = (
            window_events
            | 'Group By User ID' >> beam.Map(lambda elem: (elem['user'], elem['level']))
            | 'Compute Max Level Per User' >> beam.CombinePerKey(max)
        )

        (user_max_level
         | "FormatFieldValueFn" >> beam.ParDo(FormatFieldValueFn())
        )

        p.run().wait_until_finish()
```

Then I put one new zip file to `GCS`, then pipeline of dataflow is running , but hang in `Compute Max Level Per User`

[image]

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Can you add code for the CombineFn used in the CombinePerKey?

Comment: oops nevermind. I see it's just the Python `max` builtin function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root of the problem likely has to do with watermarks and lateness on the Combine transform (you can read a summary of the concept [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#watermarks-and-late-data)). The reason watermarks are possibly an issue is because you set the timestamps for your elements manually, using `beam.Map`, even though your watermarks have already been set when reading from the PubSub source, since it is an unbounded source which sets its own timestamps.

The [`ReadFromPubSub` transform](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.14.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub.ReadFromPubSub) has a parameter labeled `timestamp_attribute` which is the intended way to use an attribute timestamp with PubSub. If you set this parameter to `ts` then `ReadFromPubSub` should emit elements with timestamps already set to `ts`, and the watermark should be set appropriately as well.

If that doesn't work, there are other things you can look at. Double checking that the timestamps are being set correctly is a good initial step (compare the timestamps of the elements produced by `ReadFromPubSub` to the value of `ts`). Another possibility is that setting a trigger on the windows might help. A [processing time trigger](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#processing-time-triggers), for example, might be able to prevent windows from waiting forever for the watermark to catch up, although it might not be appropriate based on the needs of your pipeline. As an extra note, the metrics you screenshotted above can sometimes be unreliable for python streaming, so if you need to do fine-grained debugging you may have better luck by making your transforms output logs you can read through.